# Multiple functions inside of ng-style

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ng-style

I have an issue with some coloring in my table. I have created a function almost identical to another function I am using in my style tag for my table.

Is there a way to call two functions within one style tag in Angular? (I'm new to angular so i'm not 100% sure if it's called a style tag or not.)

The two functions I would like to include are isPTO and isHol. At the moment I am only able to get isPTO to show up correctly or isHol, but I cannot figure out how to get both to show up.

Here is my code:

### Index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="app.css" />
      <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/domo.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>      
  </head>
  <body ng-app="rcr_sched" ng-controller="main">
      <div id="mydiv">
        <table>
            <tr id="printc"><button id="print" class="fa fa-print fa-3x" onclick="print('#mydiv')"></button>
            <button id="print2" onclick="print('#mydiv')">Print Page</button>
            </tr>
            <tr height="40" id="header">
                <th ng-repeat="prop in columns">{{prop.date}}</th>
            </tr>  
            <tr ng-repeat="r in data">
                <td align="center" ng-repeat="prop2 in columns" class="{{getColor(r.TeamRank, r.Team, prop2.title)}}" style="{{isPTO(prop2.title, 'PTO' + prop2.title, r['PTO' + prop2.title])}}">
                    {{r[prop2.title]}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
          <hr id="end">
      </div>      
  </body>
</html>
```

### App.js

```
var app = angular.module('rcr_sched',['ngRoute']);

 app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
       .when('/',{
           templateUrl:'index.html',
           controller:'main'
       })
       .when('drill',{
           templateUrl:'drill.html'
       })
//       .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});  
    }
 ]);
//Range Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

app.controller('main', ['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $location){
        $scope.goNext = function(view){
            $location.path('/');
        }
        $scope.data = [];
        $scope.columns = [];
        $scope.currentDate = new Date();
        $scope.calculateDate = function() {
            var x = new Date();
            return {
                'MonThisWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() - (x.getDay() - 1)), title:'MonThisWk'},
                'TueThisWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() - (x.getDay() - 2)),title:'TueThisWk'},
                'WedThisWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() - (x.getDay() - 3)),title:'WedThisWk'},
                'ThuThisWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() - (x.getDay() - 4)),title:'ThuThisWk'},
                'FriThisWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() - (x.getDay() - 5)),title:'FriThisWk'},
                'MonNextWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 7 - (x.getDay() - 1)),title:'MonNextWk'},
                'TueNextWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 7 - (x.getDay() - 2)),title:'TueNextWk'},
                'WedNextWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 7 - (x.getDay() - 3)),title:'WedNextWk'},
                'ThuNextWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 7 - (x.getDay() - 4)),title:'ThuNextWk'},
                'FriNextWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 7 - (x.getDay() - 5)),title:'FriNextWk'},
                'Mon2Wks': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 14 - (x.getDay() - 1)),title:'Mon2Wks'},
                'Tue2Wks': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 14 - (x.getDay() - 2)),title:'Tue2Wks'},
                'Wed2Wks': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 14 - (x.getDay() - 3)),title:'Wed2Wks'},
                'Thu2Wks': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 14 - (x.getDay() - 4)),title:'Thu2Wks'},
                'Fri2Wks': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 14 - (x.getDay() - 5)), title:'Fri2Wks'}
            }
        }
        $scope.isPTO = function(rowTitle, ptoTitle, value) {
            if (rowTitle == (ptoTitle.replace('PTO', '')) && value) {
                return 'background-color: #7DD961;';
            }
            return '';
        }
        $scope.isHol = function(rowTitle, holTitle, value ){
            if (rowTitle == (holTitle.replace('Hol', '')) && value){
                return 'background-color: #AA8CC5;';
            }
            return '';
        }

        function print(elem){
            Popup($('<div/>').append($(elem).clone()).html());
        }

        function Popup(data) 
{
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=400,width=600');
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');
    mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ddincludes/mainstyle.css" type="text/css" />');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body>');
    mywindow.document.write(data);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');


    mywindow.print();
  //  mywindow.close();
    return true;
}

        $scope.dateOptions = $scope.calculateDate();
        $scope.getColor = function(teamRank, team, prop) {
            let today = new Date();

            if (prop == 'Team' || prop == 'TeamMember') 
            {
                if (team == 'Unassigned') 
                {
                    return "grayClass";
                }
                else if (team == 'Gold One') 
                {
                    return "goldClass";
                }
                else if (team == 'Red One' || team == 'Red Two') 
                {
                    return "redClass";
                }
                else if (team == 'Blue One' || team == 'Blue Two') {
                    return "blueClass"
                }
                else if (team == 'Green One') 
                {
                    return "greenClass";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "grayClass";
                }
            }
            if(prop == 'MonThisWk' || prop == 'Mon2Wks')
           {
               if(today.getDay() == 1)
               {
                    return "highlightClass";   
               } 
           }
           if(prop == 'TueThisWk' || prop == 'Tue2Wks')
           {
               if(today.getDay() == 2)
               {
                    return "highlightClass";   
               }
           }
           if(prop == 'WedThisWk' || prop == 'Wed2Wks')
           {
               if(today.getDay() == 3)
               {
                    return "highlightClass";   
               }
           }
           if(prop == 'ThuThisWk' || prop == 'Thu2Wks')
           {
               if(today.getDay() == 4)
               {
                    return "highlightClass";   
               }
           }
            if(prop == 'FriThisWk' || prop == 'Fri2Wks')
           {
               if(today.getDay() == 5)
               {
                    return "highlightClass";   
               }
           }

        }

        domo.get('data/v1/master?fields=Team,TeamMember,TotalJobs,NDD,Past,MonThisWk,TueThisWk,WedThisWk,ThuThisWk,FriThisWk,MonNextWk,TueNextWk,WedNextWk,ThuNextWk,FriNextWk,Mon2Wks,Tue2Wks,Wed2Wks,Thu2Wks,Fri2Wks,FutureDates,TotalJobs,PTOMonThisWk,PTOTueThisWk,PTOWedThisWk,PTOThuThisWk,PTOFriThisWk,PTOMon2Wks,PTOTue2Wks,PTOWed2Wks,PTOThu2Wks,PTOFri2Wks,PTOMonNextWk,PTOTueNextWk,PTOWedNextWk,PTOThuNextWk,PTOFriNextWk,HolMonThisWk,HolTueThisWk,HolWedThisWk,HolThuThisWk,HolFriThisWk,HolMonNextWk,HolTueNextWk,HolWedNextWk,HolThuNextWk,HolFriNextWk,HolMon2Wks,HolTue2Wks,HolWed2Wks,HolThu2Wks,HolFri2Wks&groupby=TeamRank,Team,TeamMember&orderby=TeamRank')
            .then(function(data){
                $scope.data = data;
                for (prop in data[0]) {
                    if ($scope.dateOptions[prop]) {
                        var newDate = $scope.dateOptions[prop];
                        var formattedProp = {date: (newDate.date.getMonth() + 1).toString() + '/' + newDate.date.getDate().toString(), title: newDate.title};
                    }
                    else {
                        var formattedProp = {date: prop, title: prop};
                    }
                    $scope.columns.push(formattedProp);
                }
                $scope.$apply();
            })
    }]);

app.controller('drill', ['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $location){
        $scope.goNext = function(view){
            $location.path('drill');
        }
        $scope.data = [];
        $scope.columns = [];
        $scope.currentDate = new Date();
        $scope.calculateDate = function() {
            var x = new Date();
            return {
                'MonThisWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() - (x.getDay() - 1)), title:'MonThisWk'},
                'TueThisWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() - (x.getDay() - 2)),title:'TueThisWk'},
                'WedThisWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() - (x.getDay() - 3)),title:'WedThisWk'},
                'ThuThisWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() - (x.getDay() - 4)),title:'ThuThisWk'},
                'FriThisWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() - (x.getDay() - 5)),title:'FriThisWk'},
                'MonNextWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 7 - (x.getDay() - 1)),title:'MonNextWk'},
                'TueNextWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 7 - (x.getDay() - 2)),title:'TueNextWk'},
                'WedNextWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 7 - (x.getDay() - 3)),title:'WedNextWk'},
                'ThuNextWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 7 - (x.getDay() - 4)),title:'ThuNextWk'},
                'FriNextWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 7 - (x.getDay() - 5)),title:'FriNextWk'},
                'Mon2Wks': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 14 - (x.getDay() - 1)),title:'Mon2Wks'},
                'Tue2Wks': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 14 - (x.getDay() - 2)),title:'Tue2Wks'},
                'Wed2Wks': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 14 - (x.getDay() - 3)),title:'Wed2Wks'},
                'Thu2Wks': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 14 - (x.getDay() - 4)),title:'Thu2Wks'},
                'Fri2Wks': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 14 - (x.getDay() - 5)), title:'Fri2Wks'}
            }
        }
        $scope.isPTO = function(rowTitle, ptoTitle, value) {
            if (rowTitle == (ptoTitle.replace('PTO', '')) && value) {
                return 'background-color: #32CD32;';
            }
            return '';
        }

        function print(elem){
            Popup($('<div/>').append($(elem).clone()).html());
        }

        function Popup(data) 
{
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=400,width=600');
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');
    mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ddincludes/mainstyle.css" type="text/css" />');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body>');
    mywindow.document.write(data);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');


    mywindow.print();
  //  mywindow.close();
    return true;
}

        $scope.dateOptions = $scope.calculateDate();
        $scope.getColor = function(teamRank, team, prop) {
            let today = new Date();

            if (prop == 'Team' || prop == 'TeamMember') 
            {
                if (team == 'Unassigned') 
                {
                    return "grayClass";
                }
                else if (team == 'Gold One') 
                {
                    return "goldClass";
                }
                else if (team == 'Red One' || team == 'Red Two') 
                {
                    return "redClass";
                }
                else if (team == 'Blue One' || team == 'Blue Two') {
                    return "blueClass"
                }
                else if (team == 'Green One') 
                {
                    return "greenClass";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "grayClass";
                }
            }
            if(prop == 'MonThisWk' || prop == 'Mon2Wks')
           {
               if(today.getDay() == 1)
               {
                    return "highlightClass";   
               } 
           }
           if(prop == 'TueThisWk' || prop == 'Tue2Wks')
           {
               if(today.getDay() == 2)
               {
                    return "highlightClass";   
               }
           }
           if(prop == 'WedThisWk' || prop == 'Wed2Wks')
           {
               if(today.getDay() == 3)
               {
                    return "highlightClass";   
               }
           }
           if(prop == 'ThuThisWk' || prop == 'Thu2Wks')
           {
               if(today.getDay() == 4)
               {
                    return "highlightClass";   
               }
           }
            if(prop == 'FriThisWk' || prop == 'Fri2Wks')
           {
               if(today.getDay() == 5)
               {
                    return "highlightClass";   
               }
           }

        }

        domo.get('data/v1/master?fields=Team,TeamMember,JobNumber&groupby=TeamRank,Team,TeamMember&orderby=TeamRank')
            .then(function(data){
                $scope.data = data;
                for (prop in data[0]) {
                    if ($scope.dateOptions[prop]) {
                        var newDate = $scope.dateOptions[prop];
                        var formattedProp = {date: (newDate.date.getMonth() + 1).toString() + '/' + newDate.date.getDate().toString(), title: newDate.title};
                    }
                    else {
                        var formattedProp = {date: prop, title: prop};
                    }
                    $scope.columns.push(formattedProp);
                }
                $scope.$apply();
            })
    }]);
```

### App.css

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: xx-small;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    -moz-print-color-adjust: exact;
}

a{
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 15px
}

table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th{
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

td{
    border: 2px solid white;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

td{
    background-color: #ececec;
}

hr {
    margin: 0;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    width: 1504px;
}

.redClass {
    background-color: #ffbbb3;
}

.blueClass {
    background-color: #b3d1ff;
}

.grayClass {
    background-color: #D9D9D9;
}

.goldClass {
    background-color: #efe68f;
}

.greenClass {
    background-color: #b0e89f;
}

.ptoClass {
    background-color: #52D08F;
}

.highlightClass {
    background-color: #FEF65B;
}


.hideClass {
    background-color: white;
    color: white;
}
#header{
    background-color: #D9D9D9;
    font-size: 19px;
}

#print{
    background-color: white;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    border: none;
}

#print2{
    border: none;
    background-color: white;
    align-content: right;
/*    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;*/
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;

}
td:nth-child(1){
    border-left-color: #2F4F4F;
}
td:nth-child(2){
    border-right-color: #2F4F4F;
}
td:nth-child(3){
    border-right-color: #2F4F4F;
}
td:nth-child(4){
    border-right-color: #2F4F4F;
}
td:nth-child(9){
    border-right-color: #2F4F4F;
}
td:nth-child(14){
    border-right-color: #2F4F4F;
}
td:nth-child(19){
    border-right-color: #2F4F4F;
}

td:nth-child(20){
    border-right-color: #2F4F4F; 
}
td:nth-child(21){
    border-right-color: black;
}
td:nth-child(n+3){
    font-weight:bold;
}

th:nth-child(n+22){
    display: none;
}

td:nth-child(n+22) {
    display: none;    
}



@media print{
    #print{
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    #print2{
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    #link{
        display: none;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if this is the proper way to do this, but I found that if I put the functions like this: `style="{{isPTO(prop2.title, 'PTO' + prop2.title, r['PTO' + prop2.title]) || isHol(prop2.title, 'Hol' + prop2.title, r['Hol' + prop2.title])}}"`

It worked exactly the way I wanted. I'm answering this so hopefully it will help someone else who might have a similar question.